# Plot_ly 3d Plotting Issue with Work-Around

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am using `plot_ly` and I tried:

```
plot_ly(x = c(0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0), 
        y = c(0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0), 
        z = c(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0), 
        type = 'mesh3d') # nowork.png
```

Resulting in no visible plot:

[image: plot-ly mesh3d not visible]

However, by adding a small offset:

```
plot_ly(x = c(0.0,1.0,1.0000001,0.0000001), 
        y = c(0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0), 
        z = c(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0), 
        type = 'mesh3d') # works.png
```

I get what I expected:

[image: plot_ly mesh3d visibile]

So why the difference?  Is there a fix other than this kludgey work-around?